# Simple php UnitTtests but kind of stuck

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

i started few time ago to do some unit testings for my functions but i really can't find how to do it properly for this function. I think it's really easy but there's something i'm missing.

```
    /**
 * Tests model->function()
 */
public function testFunction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated model->testFunction()
    $this->markTestIncomplete ( "function test not implemented" );
    $this->model->testFunction('', '5');
    $this->model->testFunction('test', '');
    $this->model->testFunction('test', 'a');
    $this->model->testFunction('1', '5');

}
```

This is what i have and phpUnit just ignore those tests.
What i want is to test my function (which needs 2 parameters, both integers) and check :

- Are both parameters not null ?
- Are both parameters from type integer ?

Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement

```
$this->markTestIncomplete ()
```

will cause PHPUnit to pass over this test file and mark it with an I in the output for not completed (executed).

Secondly, the format for your tests is incorrect.  You need to create the object, then test it.

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->model = new model();
}

public function testFunction()
{
    $this->assertEquals('test', $this->model->Function(5));  // Test what the function should return, using parameters replacing the 5
}
```

The Function should accept a parameter based on what I see in your attempt.  Then this function will return something, that you can evaluate against.

Optionally, you can use a dataProvider to provide multiple values to the test and see the output.  Check the PHPUnit manual for more information.